# Why is the Hilbert polynomial of projective varieties an invariant?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Suppose $S=k[x_0,...,x_n]$ and $M$ is the homogeneous coordinate ring of some projective variety in $P^n$. Then $M$ is a graded $S$ module. By a theorem of Hilbert-Serre, Hilbert polynomial is defined to be the unique polynomial, $P_M$, such that $P_M(l)=\dim_k (M_l)$.

Is the Hilbert polynomial an invariant under birational map or isomorphism? Why?

Comment: No... The Hilbert polynomial is defined as a function of the specific projective embedding. For instance, if you embed $\mathbb{P}^1$ in $\mathbb{P}^n$ by Veronese, the polynomial remains affine but its dominant coefficient is going to be $n$ (I think), while for $\mathbb{P}^1 \rightarrow \mathbb{P}^1$ the Hilbert polynomial is $X+1$ (I think).

Comment: @Mindlack I agree with you, thank you!

Comment: @Mindlack that looks like an answer to me - please consider recording it as such below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, the Hilbert polynomial is defined as a function of the specific projective embedding. Its degree is an invariant (always the dimension of the projective variety), but the general polynomial isn’t.

For instance, the Hilbert polynomial of the identity inclusion $\mathbb{P}^1 \subset \mathbb{P}^1$ is $H(T)=T+1$. But the Hilbert polynomial of the Veronese embedding $\mathbb{P}^1 \longmapsto \mathbb{P}^n$ is $H(T)=nT+1$ (I think).